# How to receive datastream until Enter key is pressed in TCP?

Tags: c#, server, client, chatroom

I'm making a TCP chatroom where multiple clients can connect to a TCP server. I'm able to relay the messages that I send to all the clients, but unfortunately it's sending every single letter as it is typed and that is messing up the format. The behavior I want is to send the message only when the "Enter" key is pressed.

Another problem I'm having is that when I ask for the username, it only reads in the first character of the string I type as the username. I tried debugging it, but couldn't figure out the issue. Below are my methods for sending data and receiving data.

```
    public void ReadData(object socket)
    {
        Socket s = (Socket)socket;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int k = 0;
        while (true)
        {               
            k = s.Receive(buffer);
            // event that triggers the Message() method
            SendGlobalMessage(s, buffer.GetString(k));  
        }
    }

    public void Message(Socket s, string msg)
    {
        string newMsg = String.Format("[{0}: {1}]", Connections[s], msg);
        foreach (Socket st in Connections.Keys)
        {
            st.Send(newMsg.ToByteArray());
        }
    }
```

Please show me examples of what I could do differently so I can grasp a firm idea of what to change. Thank you.

Comment: You don't want the client to format the message that will be sent, instead let the server do it. (`String.Format("[{0}: {1}]", Connections[s], msg);`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is *WinForms*

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   textBox1.KeyPress += CheckEnterKeyPress;
}

private void CheckEnterKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
   {
      var textbox = sender as TextBox;
      Message(socket, textbox.Text);
   }
}
```